# charAt not working in java fraction calculator

Tags: java, if-statement, charat

This code returns false even when input has an underscore. 
  Input would be something like 1_3/4 + 3 and would return 4_3/4

```
  String[] Separated = fraction.split(" "); //Splits the tokens up
  String firstToken = Separated[0]; // I created this to try to troubleshoot
  boolean Mixed = true; //This would determine how much I will need to split up
  for(int i = 0; i < firstToken.length(); i++) {
     if(firstToken.charAt(i) == '_') { 
        Mixed = true;
     }
     else {
        Mixed = false;
     }
  }
```

Comment: charAt is working just fine. On the other hand, *what prevents Mixed from being set back to false?*

Comment: oh right my bad lol thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "contains" instead of that for loop:

```
boolean mixed = firstToken.contains("_");
```

Please, use lower case variable names in java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the position of underscore character a quick fix to our code can be:

```
String firstToken = "_"; // I created this to try to troubleshoot
    boolean Mixed = true; //This would determine how much I will need to split up
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < firstToken.length(); i++) {
        if(firstToken.charAt(i) == '_') {
            Mixed = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            Mixed = false;
        }
    }
    //i gives the index of underscore
```

There are cleaner ways to do it though.
This should get the index of underscore

```
    String firstToken = Seperated[0]; // I created this to try to troubleshoot     
    int index==firstToken.indexOf('_');
```